# Python 3.3 Sorting a tuple list with multiple keys

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I'm having a bit of a problem (encountered during a Project Euler problem) in that I have a list of lists of tuples e.g.

```
  [...
    [(-119, 359), (668, -609), (-358, -494)], 
    [(440, 929), (968, 214), (760, -857)], 
    [(-700, 785), (838, 29), (-216, 411)], 
    [(-770, -458), (-325, -53), (-505, 633)],
  ...]
```

What I want to do is sort them by the tuple with the smallest first value, but if they are equal to then compare the second values and order by the smallest of these. I've been looking about and can't seem to find a way to do this. The only thing I have found is the old python 2.x version of sorted where it is given a cmp argument.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Regards,

Ybrad

Edit:

I just realised the above is worded slightly incorrectly. What I want to do is sort the tuples within each sub-list, not the list of lists as a whole.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily do that as:

```
a = [sorted(i) for i in a]

>>> print a
[[(-358, -494), (-119, 359), (668, -609)],
 [(440, 929), (760, -857), (968, 214)],
 [(-700, 785), (-216, 411), (838, 29)],
 [(-770, -458), (-505, 633), (-325, -53)]]
```

For your second request, you can do it as:

```
a = [sorted(i, key=lambda i: (i[0], -i[1])) for i in a]
```

Comment: That should work thanks, but suppose that instead of smallest second element when the first match we want to order largest to smallest. How would that be achieved.

Comment: @user163911, You mean sort the tuples in decending order?

Comment: More like in SQL where you sort by first one attribute and then a second for all those where the first are equal. For example the list of names [("Doe", "Jane"), ("Burns", "Sam"), ("Farmey", "Enid"), ("Doe", "John")] to get [("Burns", "Sam"), ("Doe", "John"), ("Doe", "Jane"), ("Farmery", "Enid")]. Here it is sorted first by the last name ascending and then by second name descending. Is this possible in python?

Comment: Thanks, that should be fine and useful for the future.