# Python - sorting list of tuples based on multiple sort items

Tags: python, sorting

First, I have noticed that there are many questions posted on sorting lists of tuples, however after looking over a few posts I did not see any of the questions with this particular format for the list. Apologies in advance then for a potential repeat question, however I think this should be simple.

Let the list of tuples be this:

```
my_list = [(('G', 'J', 'I'), 1.0), (('E', 'H', 'F'), 1.0), (('F', 'H', 'G'), 0.8889), (('I', 'K', 'J'), 0.8889), (('H', 'I', 'G'), 0.8889), (('H', 'J', 'I'), 0.875)]
```

Note that each tuple in the list consists of 1: another tuple of length 3 with 3 letters, and 2: a floating point number. My sorting objective is simple then: 1st sort the list of tuples by the floating point number, 2nd break any ties in the floating point number by then sorting by the first letter in the length-3 tuple, 3rd break any ties in that letter by sorting by the 2nd letter in the length-3 tuple. Desired output would then be:

```
sorted_list = [(('E', 'H', 'F'), 1.0), (('G', 'J', 'I'), 1.0), (('F', 'H', 'G'), 0.8889),  (('H', 'I', 'G'), 0.8889), (('I', 'K', 'J'), 0.8889), (('H', 'J', 'I'), 0.875)]
```

in this particular example, sorting on the 2nd letter to break ties on the first letter did not appear, although it does in my larger dataset.

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to sort in descending order by the float, and in ascending order by the letters in the tuple? Try `key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.3 Sorting a tuple list with multiple keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454961/python-3-3-sorting-a-tuple-list-with-multiple-keys)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it: the first sort is done in reverse on the float, while the ties are broken by sorting on the inner tuple:

```
srt_lst = sorted(my_list, key=lambda (x, y): (-y, x)) #python 2
print(srt_lst)
# [(('E', 'H', 'F'), 1.0), (('G', 'J', 'I'), 1.0), (('F', 'H', 'G'), 0.8889), (('H', 'I', 'G'), 0.8889), (('I', 'K', 'J'), 0.8889), (('H', 'J', 'I'), 0.875)]
```

In Python 3, you'll have to index the lambda's single parameter to access the items and use them for sorting:

```
srt_lst = sorted(my_list, key=lambda tup: (-tup[1], tup[0]))
```

Comment: Note: tuple unpacking in `lambda` does not work in Python 3; otherwise fine.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for noting. Their Python 3 tag was missing

Comment: thanks - using python 2, and can confirm that the first solution sorted properly for me.

Comment: FWIW, I'd suggest only using the python3 variant (which works just fine on python2.x).  Just because the python2.x variant works _today_, if you use decide to port your code to python3 tomorrow, then this is just another thing you'll have to fix... (and like it or not, python3.x _is_ the future of python).